Marble as soft as a mattress
I read this in the book The Dark Forest by Cixin Liu. On page 121,

With his body, he felt the hardness of the ore and, weirdly, thought of a problem put forth by his high school physics teacher: How can you make a marble bed as soft as a Simmons mattress? The answer: Dig out a depression in that marble the exact size and shape of a human body. Then when you lie in that depression, the pressure will be evenly distributed and it would feel incredibly soft.

I wonder if this is true from a physics standpoint?

In the correct position, and for an instant, it could feel as comfortable as floating in salty water—another material that can support one's entire weight through maximal underside contact—and more comfortable than the most compliant material. But live humans don't lie motionless for long; our breathing and heartbeat deform our tissues,  and we naturally fidget and shift even when infinitely comfortable. Any such movement would make the rigidity of the stone immediately apparent.
